# template class of derived class as parameter to function - dangers?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

**EDIT: just to clarify, I understand why this code does not work,and I'm not attempting to fix it, but to understand what are the dangers if this code could compile without the semantic error.**

I have found that the following code will cause a static semantic error.
I know that it's because std::list is a template class and that means that `std::list<foo*>` is a different type than `std::list<bar*>`

My question is, if the compiler would allow this type of conversion from `std::list<bar*>` to `std::list<foo*>` in the second call to print_all , what could be the danger?

I have searched around the site but couldn't find examples to bad things that could happen.
I have also tried to think of such examples but I'm not sure that these are correct or accurate.
(for example if the compiler would allow this, could I add a foo* object into the bar list in print_all() because it was converted to list?).

```
#include <list>
using std::list;
class foo {
    // ...
};
class bar : public foo {
    // ...
};

static void print_all(list<foo*>& L) {
    // ...
}

list<foo*> LF;
list<bar*> LB;
// ...
print_all(LF); // works fine 
print_all(LB); // static semantic error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list<foo*>` and `list<bar*>` are two completely different classes, with no connection between them, other than beeing generated from the same template `std::list` (`template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class list;`). As such there isn't a conversion between them, unless the author of the template `std::list` explicitly wrote a conversion between `std::list<T, A>` and `std::list<U, A>` when `T` is a base class of `U`. And that is not written.

One way to achieve what you want is by creating template function:

```
template <class T, class A>
void print_all(std::list<T*, A>& l)
```

Now, there are a few caveats to be aware of:

I see no reason why you would make that static member. I would make it free function, **but** I would put it in a namespace with `foo` and `bar`

If you want to restrict it's usage strictly to `foo` and its derived classes you can do it with [sfinae](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template <class T, class A, class E = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<foo, T>>>
auto print_all(std::list<T*, A>& l)
{
}
```

And finally you should consider turning this into idiomatic C++ way of printing, aka streams and add the `operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::list<T*, A>&)` along with `operator<<(std::ostream, const foo&)` and maybe a virtual print function on `foo`. Here is extra important to define them in the same namespace as `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed answer,
but i did not find an answer to what bad things could happen if this code (without the changes you suggested) could compile? (if the compiler would allow the second call the print_all).

Comment: @Daniel as I've said, it's not up to the compiler. The two classes are different classes, with no relation between them, other than being generated from the same template.

Comment: @Daniel : `foo` and `bar` have an inheritance relationship between them. `std::list<foo>` and `std::list<bar>` have no relationship between them.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I'm saying that I'm interested in what dangers could be caused if this behavior was allowed.

Comment: for example this code wouldn't work with java generics as well, even though it's a different mechanism.

Comment: @Daniel you can't "allow" this behavior not because of the "dangers", but because it's simple impossible. There is no connection between the classes. That's like asking why doesn't the compiler allow the conversion between `X` and `Y` where `X` and `Y` are two completely unrelated classes.

Comment: I know and understand that they are two different unrelated classes. I'm not wishing to allow this behavior, I'm simply asking what are the dangers if it was allowed. (i edited my question and added an example). and I'm not sure, but in java, aren't they the same class with different casting to the generic parameter. so why doesn't it work there?

Comment: And i appreciate your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use one vector instead of other because are different classes, but you can convert one vector to other implicitely or explicitely, using transformation or copy/ move constructors and assignment operator. It can cost you additional performance ( and memory in case of copy) overhead, but can be a deal in your particular case.